# StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED before reaching quota limit + confusing dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm using Google Vision API for text & logo detection. When trying to run 300 annotation requests, each with up to 6 images, I'm getting this error (python library):

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).)>
```

I'm making up to 8 concurrent requests, whole process takes about 65 seconds.

According to [Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/vision/quotas) I should be able to:

- make 600 requests per minute
- send up to 16 images per request

There's also a limit for image size & JSON request object size, but with images like [this one](https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/PPECA8dS3MLu6D2ijeiw) (under 50KB), that should not be a problem (right?).

I could ask for a quota increase, but since I'm not able to get to the default 600 req/min, I would have to make a guess (or is my quota math incorrect?)

Looking at Google Cloud Vision API dashboard confuses me even more, here are **results for the same minute**, just after a page refresh:
[image]

Did anyone have a similar issue? I would like to reach 300req/min threshold (at least).

Comment: I'm guessing that 1 requests with 4 images (for text detection) counts as 4 text detection requests. If that's true, than quota page is a bit confusing.

Comment: Based on the second graph, the number of requests exceeds the quota threshold. This is the reason behind the error message you are receiving. However, the inconsistent graph results is not a normal behavior. If this issue is still ongoing, I would strongly recommend you create a public issue[1] detailing the inconsistencies observed with specific instances. This will help identify why this behavior is occurring. To clarify your inquiry in the comment, if the 4 images were in the same request, it only counts as one request towards your quota. [1]https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new